# Auto increment the VARCHAR value obtained from Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the value of DRSYSCODE from DB, Now i need to auto increment the value while insertion

Am getting the value in this Format MOB000571 now on insertion i need to increment to MOB000572, for this am using the below code but am unable to achieve it, In return am getting the value only 1 ,Please help me in this

```
$sql1="SELECT DRSYSCODE FROM DOCTORDETAILS  ORDER BY DRSYSCODE DESC LIMIT 1";
    $query=mysql_query($sql1);
    if (!$sql1) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $output_array2=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $ids=$row['DRSYSCODE'];

    }
    echo $ids;
    if($ids){
        $su=1;
        echo $num =$ids+$su;
        $unique=$num;
    }

    echo $unique;
```

Comment: Are you sure that $ids has something after retrieving it from database?

Comment: yes am getting the value $id=MOB000571  from DB

Comment: You can't increment a value that has non numeric characters. Try the answer from  Being Sunny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$num =$ids+$su;` use this:

```
$num = 'MOB' . str_pad($su + substr($ids, 3), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy @Neodan

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
$pieces = explode("MOB", $string);
$autoinc_add = 1+$pieces[1];
$your_latest_autoincrement_value = str_pad($autoinc_add, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $your_latest_autoincrement_value;
```

Comment: Why you do not use `substr`?

Comment: Thanks buddy @Being Sunny

Comment: @Neodan Yes `substr` is also a good choice but explode came to my mind first that's why I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to add 1, an integer to a string of text. You need to break up the string of text into the text part and the number part first into two separate variables (unless the 'MOB' is always the first three characters, or unless there are always three characters followed by six digits in your DRSYSCODE) then add 1 to the number part and then concatenate them together again before inserting. For example, if the DRSYSCODE is always AAAxxxxxx ('A' being characters and 'x' being digits), you could do something like:

```
if($ids){
    $alpha = substr($ids, 0, 3); // Get the first three characters and put them in $alpha
    $numeric = substr($ids, 3, 6); // Get the following six digits and put them in $numeric
    $numeric++; // Add one to $numeric
    $numeric = str_pad($numeric, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // Pad $numeric with leading zeros
    $newids = $alpha.$numeric; // Concatenate the two variables into $newids
    }
```

I hope this helps. I see other places in your code where it could be simplified but that isn't part of your question. All the best to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should split your id in two part, first one is the letters (MOB, in this case) and the second part is the numbers (000571) and then you should be able to add 1 to the numbers and then concatenate both letters and the incremented numbers. This is because you're trying to add 1 to a string, not an interger or a float value. String are only for characters which means you can't do math on them.

I would replace the `if(ids) {...}` part by this

```
if($ids){
    $su=1;
    $splitedid = preg_split('/(?<=[a-zA-z])(?=[0-9]+)/',$ids); //Split in chars and numbers
    $zeros = substr_count($splitedid[1], '0'); //Count the number of zeros before the number
    $num = $splitedid[1]+$su; //Add one to the number
    $unique = $splitedid[0]; //Set $unique as the chars (MOB in your case)
    for ($i=0; $i < $zeros; $i++) { //Add to $unique the zeros that were in front of the number
      $unique .= '0';
    }
    $unique .= $num; //Add the number (572 = 571 + 1) to $unique so $unique is 'MOB000572'
}
```

Hope it helps !